# "... one of its kind..." or "......a one of its kind."

Tags: word-choice

I am really confused what to choose in the following sentence.

"We are one of its kind app that extends you exciting offers."
Is this correct, or should I write
"We are **a** one of its kind app that extends you exciting offers"?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-of-a-kind

In the above website, they haven't used 'a'.

I tried looking for an answer in this link: ["one of a kind" idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181792/one-of-a-kind-idiom/181882), but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

#### Hyphenated adjectives

Adjectives like "one of its kind" should be written with hyphens, to remove the exact problem that's making it difficult for you to make a decision here.

To make your decision simpler, replace "one of its kind" with "yellow", a one-word adjective, and look at your two options again.

- We are yellow app ...
- We are **a** yellow app ...

It obviously should be "a yellow app".  Now that you've established that you need the article "a" in place, change the adjective back again.

- We are a one-of-its-kind app ...

#### We're an app?

Your sentence is grammatically correct (with "a"), but doesn't make much sense, even for advertising copy. "We", normally used to for a group of people, really cannot be "an app", a piece of computer software.

I'd suggest a different verb:

- We **make** a one-of-its-kind app
- We **have created** a ...   *the change in tense to past-perfect suggest you've achieved this just recently*
- We **offer** a ...

#### Isn't everything "one of its kind"?

Finally, "one of *its* kind" is probably not the description you want. It is not an idiom in English, and so it has its literal meaning: just one of (possibly many) things of the same type.

The very similar "one of *a* kind" is the phrase that has the idiomatic meaning of "unique".